# function $(-2)^{x}$

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation

What is the real and imaginary parts for the function $f(x)=(-2)^{x}$ ?
Is there a unique solution to this question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since $-2 = 2e^{i\pi}$, then $\ln(-2) = \ln(2)+i(\pi+2k\pi) = \ln(2)+i(2k+1)\pi$ are the complex logarithm values of $\ln(-2)$.

Since $a^x = e^{x\ln(a)}$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
(-2)^x &= \exp(x\ln(-2))\\
 &= \exp\left(x\Bigl( \ln(2) + i(2k+1)\pi\Bigr)\right)\\
&= \exp(x\ln(2) + ix(2k+1)\pi)\\
&= e^{x\ln(2)} e^{ix(2k+1)\pi}\\
&= 2^x\Bigl( \cos(x(2k+1)\pi) + i\sin(x(2k+1)\pi)\Bigr)\\
&= 2^x\cos(x(2k+1)\pi) + i2^x\sin(x(2k+1)\pi).
\end{align*}$$
So for integer $k$, the different values of $(-2)^x$ have real part $2^x\cos\Bigl(x(2k+1)\pi\Bigr)$, and complex part $2^x\sin\Bigl(x(2k+1)\pi\Bigr)$.

**Added.** To take the *principal value* of the logarithm (which requires the imaginary part to lie in $(-\pi,\pi]$, then you use $k=0$.

Comment: Arturo, you have a small typo at the start of the second sentence =)

Comment: @Adrián: Those darned curly brackets... Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a convention/definition to take one of these solutions as "the solution" ?

Comment: @Austin: You can take the principal branch of the complex logarithm, which is the one where the imaginary part is between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, not including $-\pi$. That meanst taking $k=0$ above.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: by definition, $a^x = e^{x \log a}$.  Complicating matters: there are infinitely many branches of the log, corresponding to branches of $a^x$.

Comment: additional hint: $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta $